# Hide Terminal and still receive input

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, python-2.7, nohup

I want to run a python script that basically uses the terminal for certain commands, but I don't want it to show the terminal. I've tried running the script as `nohup file.py &` - this works and I can close the terminal after that but my script still has points where it wants to put input into the terminal, this is a problem because `nohup` stops all input.

I was wondering if there was a way to make it so the terminal was hidden to the user but could still get input from my script through `os.system()`?